# Can't install elementary OS because my monitor doesn't support the default resolution

Tags: resolution

When I boot into the flash drive and try to install it, the screen says "unsupported" and there's nothing I can do except turning off the PC.
Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Put the usb stick to a working operating system, open it go to /boot directory find the configuration file and open it and uncomment disable_overscan=1 (if this parameter is 0 then set it to 1).